# What's happening in this JQuery code?

Tags: jquery

Sorry for this very basic JQuery question. I created 'mytest' jquery function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.mytest = function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
}
```

Now if I call it like this everything is perfect:

```
$("#someid").mytest();
```

It alerts "someid". But if I do something like this:

```
$("#someid, #anotherid, #moreids").mytest();
```

this function only alerts "someid". Of course "anotherid" and "moreids" exist.

Why mytest() is not working and what is the right code for this function?

Comment: Its not a basic question. You're extending jQuery library. Thats good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is adding a "plugin" to jQuery that makes your function available on jQuery instances. The reason you're only seeing one ID in your function is that you're using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), which only retrieves the *first* element's attribute. (Also, you **really** don't need `attr` to get an `id` value.)

Your function should look something like this ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ujaxef)):

```
jQuery.fn.mytest = function () {
    var ids = jQuery.map(this, function(elm) {
        return elm.id;
    });
    alert(ids.join(","));
};
```

...to show the `id` values (if any) of each element in the currently-matched set.

Or you could do it with a simple loop rather than with `jQuery.map` ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ujaxef/2)):

```
jQuery.fn.mytest = function () {
    var ids, index, elm;

    ids = [];
    for (index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
        elm = this[index];
        if (elm.id) {
            ids.push(elm.id);
        }
    }
    alert(ids.join(","));
};
```

Also, note that within a jQuery plug-in function, `this` is the current jQuery instance, so you don't need (or want) to pass it through `$()` to create a jQuery wrapper around the element (you do that in event handlers, not plug-ins). So when I do `this.length` in the second example above, I'm using the `length` property of the jQuery instance that we're currently operating on. When I index into `this` using bracketed notation (`elm = this[index];`), I'm indexing into the jQuery instance's matched set of elements (like the [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method, but more directly).

Comment: +1 Did not know the difference with `this` in the two contexts. This renders my sample even *more* un-elegant :)

Answer (score 3):

This is due to [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1):

> Get the value of an attribute for **the first element** in the set of matched elements. (my emphasis)

The resolution:

> The `.attr()` method gets the attribute value for only the *first* element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's `.each()` or `.map()` method.

E.g.,

```
jQuery.fn.mytest = function () {
    var ids = [];
    $(this).each(function() {
        ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    alert(ids);
}
```

(Untested, see also [*Utilizing the awesome power of jQuery to access properties of an element*](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element).)

**Disclaimer**
This is really what `.map()` is for. Read the above as a demo of the *idea*, not the *implementation of said idea* :)

Comment: You don't need (or want) to do `$(this)` within the plugin function, `this` is the jQuery instance, not a raw element. And there's no reason whatsoever for using `attr` to get an `id` value, it's just a lot of extra, unnecessary work.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yup, I just read that in you answer (see comment) :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
jQuery.fn.mytest = function () {
    return this.each(function(){
       alert(this.id);
    });
}
```

Have a read of http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring which describes what you need to know when you try to create plugins.

Using *`return this.each(..)`* enables chaining of your plugin so you can do  `$('#something, #somethingelse').mytest().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting multiple elements so...you also need to loop through that elements to alert every single id. Now you only get the first id. So it should be like:

```
jQuery.fn.mytest = function () { 
    return $(this).each(function(){ 
       alert($(this).attr('id')); 
    }); 
}
```

Not tested...